# getting an object from a consult with js

Tags: javascript, mysql

Okay, I'm trying to get the value from a consult, all looks fine and the consult works but at the moment of pass it to a const, it does not get the object.

```
  let selectid = await pool.query(
    `SELECT ID_user FROM user WHERE User_email='${email_consulted}'`
  );

  const id = selectid.ID_user
```

What's could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this example (found here: https://node-postgres.com/api/pool), pool.query returns a promise where result is some kind of an object with 'rows' property:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()
pool.query('SELECT $1::text as name', ['brianc'], (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack)
  }
  console.log(result.rows[0].name) // brianc
})
```

Considering you are doing 'await', I believe you can refer to result entity like this:

```
const id = selectid.rows[0].ID_user
```

Answer (score 0):

The query return an array so you have to assign the index. It might be:

```
const id = selectid[0].ID_user
```